# CheckBox - Exibir conteúdo de acordo com opção ativa (clicada)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando exibir determinado conteúdo de acordo com o checkbox selecionado, até esta etapa tudo ok, consegui fazer com que o conteúdo seja exibido.

Agora vem a segunda parte que é onde estou apanhando miseravelmente, que é fazer com que o item selecionado fique com uma borda para marcar como selecionado, fiz um class, especialmente para tal, chamada "borda" que deveria ser ativada de acordo com o item selecionado, porem a marcação não esta ocorrendo como deveria.

O Item não esta sendo marcado e o itens que já foram clicados não estão ocultando após clicar em outra opção do select.

Estou criando os eventos com a opção "onclick", segue abaixo o código:

```js
    
   
   function itemSelect(elem) {
        $('.closed').hide();
        var si = $(elem).val();
        switch (si) {
            case '1':
                $('.item-1').fadeIn();
                $('#1').addClass('borda');
                break;
            case '2':
                $('.item-2').fadeIn();
                $('#2').addClass('borda');
                break;
            case '3':
                $('.item-3').fadeIn();
                $('#3').addClass('borda');
                break;
            case '4':
                $('.item-4').fadeIn();
                $('#4').addClass('borda');
                break;
            
        }
    }
```

```css
.borda {
        border: 1px solid red;
        padding: 10px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .closed {
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
 <label>Opção 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="1" id="1" value="1" onclick="return itemSelect(this)"/><br>
  <label>Opção 2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="1" id="2" value="2" onclick="return itemSelect(this)"/><br>
  <label>Opção 3</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="1" id="3" value="3" onclick="return itemSelect(this)"/><br>
  <label>Opção 4</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="1" id="4" value="4" onclick="return itemSelect(this)"/>
</form>
 
<div class="item-1 closed " style="display:none">Item 1</div>
<div class="item-2 closed " style="display:none">Item 2</div>
<div class="item-3 closed " style="display:none">Item 3</div>
<div class="item-4 closed " style="display:none">Item 4</div>
```

Comment: tu quer aplicar a borda onde? No checkbox?

Comment: Sim, desculpe. Não percebi que não tinha informado este detalhe. Na realidade no exemplo que irei mandar a faculdade uso uma imagem como item que deve ser clicado para ser selecionado.

Comment: que quer dizer ocultar? seria descelecionar ou esconder?

Comment: Descelecionar, sei que com radio isso seria automático, porém para o enunciado, tem que usar checkbox!